# Auto refresh div in cakephp 2.4.x

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I want a auto refresh div in my view page in cakephp 2.4.x. The following are my code.
Controller....

```
public function latestpost(){
    $this->set('posts',$this->Post->find('all',array('limit'=>4)));
}
```

In my view page index.ctp

```
<div id="refesh">
  <?php foreach($posts as $post):
          echo $post['Post']['topic'];
  ?>
 </div>
```

and my jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  //var j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#refresh").everyTime(1000,function(i){
        $.ajax({
          url: "/my_app/posts/latestposts",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("#refresh").html(html);
          }
        })
    })
});
 $('#refresh').css({color:"green"});
});
</script>
```

Only showing the data from the data base. Refreshing is not happening automatically...
please any one help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function refreshCode(){   
  $.ajax({
          url: "/my_app/posts/latestposts",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("#refresh").html(html);
          }
        })
}

setInterval(function(){ refreshCode(); }, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try...
function refreshCode(){ 
        $.ajax({
          url: "/my_app/posts/latestposts",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("#refresh").html(html);
          }
        })
        setTimeout("refreshCode()",1000);
    } 
    refreshCode();
```